# how to show table information with select option in angular?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have 2 tables: `1 table - Stock`. `2 table - Stock_category`. In `Stock table` I have foreign key `"refer_category_id"`. I can retrieve all information from this tables and calculate how many products I have in total. How can I make it such that it will have a `"Select"` option - so that If i choose  `"Category"` it will show me all the stock that in specific category ? can someone please help? 
 this is my code:

php:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = utf8");

  if(!$connection){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }

  $query="SELECT  `refer_category_id`, `stock_id`,`product_name`,`description`,`quantity` from stock, stock_category  WHERE
   `refer_category_id` = `refer_category_id`  group by `stock_id` ";
  $queryResult = $connection->query($query);
  $queryResult2 = array();
  if( $queryResult->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
      $queryResult2[] = $row;
    }
  }
  $queryResult3 = json_encode($queryResult2);
   echo json_encode($queryResult3);
?>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('reportsCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/reports-tab/stock-report.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.stockReport = arr;


      })

         .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      })

      $scope.total = 0;
      $scope.setTotals = function(item){
            if (item){

                 $scope.total += parseInt(item.quantity);
                 return $scope.total;

            }

        }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="customer-list table table-striped" >
           <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th class="Column-Header">קטגוריה</th>
                   <th class="Column-Header">קוד מוצר</th>
                    <th class="Column-Header">שם מוצר</th>
                    <th class="Column-Header">תיאור מוצר</th>
                    <th class="Column-Header">כמות במלאי</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in stockReport" ng-init="setTotals(item)">
                    <td>{{item.refer_category_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.stock_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>

                <tr class="bg-warning">
                    <td><font size="6">סך הכל מוצרים במלאי:</font></td>
                    <td><font size="6">{{total}}</font></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you just want to filter the records on the client side? Or do you want to run new DB query after user selects another category, everytime?

Comment: @CanB  I want to filter all the products by category. if I choose for example: "camera" category it will give me all cameras that are in the stock

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8363/

So this is my suggestion for client side filtering without any extra db queries:

First, change your query to get category names. I assume that the field on database is "category_name":

```
$query="SELECT  `category_name`, `refer_category_id`, `stock_id`,`product_name`,`description`,`quantity` from stock, stock_category  WHERE `refer_category_id` = `refer_category_id`  group by `stock_id` ";
```

Then generate a select box for categories:

```
<select ng-model="selectedcategory">
    <option value="">Select a Category</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in uniqueCats" value="{{item.refer_category_id}}">{{item.category_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Use ng-show to filter data in table by categories:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in stockReport" ng-show="item.refer_category_id == selectedcategory" ng-init="setTotals(item)">
```

Lastly, this is for creating array of categories:

```
$scope.uniqueCats ={};
for(i = 0; i< $scope.stockReport.length; i++){
     $scope.uniqueCats[$scope.stockReport[i].refer_category_id] = $scope.stockReport[i];
  }
```

Comment: I noticed that to use unique filter you need Angular UI. I've removed it and added a working example.